# How to prevent LLVM clang from generating VMOVSS instructions

Tags: assembly, clang, llvm

I'm trying to find a way to do exactly what's in the title. So far I've tried adding the following options: -mno-avx -mno-sse to my build.env file, but the VMOVSS instruction is still being generated.

I selected those flags specifically because of the following page: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movss

Comment: What source code is generating this?  Is it using inline asm?  Clang definitely should not be generating a `vmovss` in a build with `-mno-avx`, unless there's a later `-mavx` build option that overrides it.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/joKra38ba  Can you provide a [mcve], including command line options that reproduce it when you run manually with `clang -O3 -S ...` or on https://godbolt.org/?  I expect you'll find that either options or inline asm was the problem, but if not, then you can report it as a clang bug.

Comment: Without a minimum reproducible example I don't see how we can help you. Please post the exact command line you use for compilation plus the code that causes it